# Locate Lips on a Face in Android

Tags: java, android, basic4android, face-detection, fpc

I have a need to detect face in a photo. Generally the face will be covering 60% of the photo. Once face is detected I have to highlight the lips of the photo with a per-defined color which is Black.

I tried to get the Face Detection feature of Android to point out lips but failed. I referred to this [documentation](http://tinyurl.com/yga8y4c) of Android to learn now to detect Face in Android.

Are there any third party libs that will allow one to Detect face and return areas of lips?

TIA

Comment: [openCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) or to some extent [Face detection in Android 4.0](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Face.html)

Comment: What are you asking for? Code in Java (Android) or for basic4android? This is not the same at all.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The document stats that the features may not be supported on all devices so this means I cannot use this.

Comment: Are you looking for java or basic4android code? They're not the same at all. And where does Free Pascal come into things?